# How to get array values in codeigniter using explode method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Query run is based on 2 id, however I get one output value

**Input:**

```
public function get_place_order_category($id)
  {
     /* $id = 1,2;*/

      $ids = explode(',',$id);
      foreach($ids as $catid)
      {
      $this->db->where('product_id =',trim($catid));
      $query = $this->db->get('products'); 

      return $query->result_array();          
      }

  }
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 12
            [product_name] => Product1
            [product_code] => pro12345
            [product_price] => 200.00
            [product_newprice] => 0.00
            [size] => 0-6M , 0-9M ,9-12M
            [product_front] => 1446200664.JPG
            [product_back] => 14462006641.JPG
            [product_left] => 14462006642.JPG
            [product_right] => 14462006643.JPG
            [product_description] => 
            [styling_tips] => 
            [category_id] => 62
            [user_id] => 5
            [status] => 1
            [parent_id] => 42
            [qty] => 4
            [promo_id] => 0
            [etc4] => 0
            [etc5] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: do you want records based on all ids passed?

Comment: output comes from `return $query->result_array();` here??

Comment: of course you'll only get one, once the `return` line hits, your method is over, either gather all the results first or just select rows with an `IN` clause

Comment: just pass the exploded ids into the `->where_in` method, no need for loops, etc.

Comment: I used wher_in query @Ghost but i got error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ('12', '13')' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`products`) WHERE `product_id` = IN ('12', '13')

Comment: @user3758766 you have an incorrect syntax, remove the `=` on the column name, you don't need to add it anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can use one global array and add result arrays to it. Try this:

```
public function get_place_order_category($id)
  {
     /* $id = 1,2;*/
     //first test here what comes in $id
      echo $id."<br/>";
      $ans_arr = array();
      $ids = explode(',',$id);
      /*test here too whats actually happens after explode weather   
      arrayhas generated and what are the element of it */
      echo "<pre>";print_r($ids);echo "<br/>";
      foreach($ids as $catid)
      {
          $this->db->where('product_id =',trim($catid));
          $query = $this->db->get('products'); 

          $ans_arr[] = $query->result_array();          
      }
      return $ans_arr;
  }
```